# how to call C# web service with Serialization object from client

Tags: c#, asp.net, webservice-client

I get method from reference after add wsdl in my C# code.

```
[System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute("Service1", RequestNamespace="http://xxx.yyy/", ResponseNamespace="http://xxx.yyy/", Use=System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal, ParameterStyle=System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Wrapped)]
        [return: System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Service1Return")]
        public Servic1Output[] Service1([System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Servicelist")] Service1Input[] Service1List) {
            object[] results = this.Invoke("Service1", new object[] {
                        Service1List});
            return ((Service1Output[])(results[0]));
            }
```

i try to call this by

```
webreference.Service1Input input = new Service1Input();
webreference.Service1Output output = new Service1Output();

input.ACTION = "First Text";
input.ACTION2 = "Second Text";

List<webreference.Service1Input> input2;
input2.Add(input);

List<webreference.Service1Output> output2;

webreference.test service = new test();
output = service.Service1(input);
```

but it result is invalid argrument. at

```
output = service.Service1(input);
```

How can i call method like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass an array of `Service1Input` objects to the `Service1(Service1Input[])` method, rather than a single instance.

```
webreference.Service1Input input = new Service1Input();
webreference.Service1Output output = new Service1Output();

input.ACTION = "First Text";
input.ACTION2 = "Second Text";

List<webreference.Service1Input> input2;
input2.Add(input);

List<webreference.Service1Output> output2;
Service1Input[] inputArray = input2.ToArray();    

webreference.test service = new test();
output = service.Service1(inputArray);
```